# Fonts : Base font of Kiln?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I would like to know if any one of you knows what font Kiln Sans & Serif are based on.

Here's the font:
http://www.yellowdesignstudio.com/fonts/kiln (images below)

I'd need it because i would like to use the non-distressed version of the font.

Font creator, Ryan, told me they made it out of scans, but does not recall base font...

Would any of you have a clue on that? What the Font gave me approximative results, but cannot find similar fonts for both the Sans & Serif version.

If nothing shows up, i might have to "un-distress" by manually, and would appreciate advice on how to do it in a not that tedious fashion...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Charles

[image: Kiln Sans]
[image: Kiln Serif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is Kiln (Sans & Serif) is based off of [Antique No. 3](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/woodentypefonts/antique3/).

I was able to track down some samples of digital versions of this typeface (see below), but they tend to deviate from the original version of Antique No. 3 as evidenced by this example published in *[Linotype Faces: One-line Specimens c. 1920](https://books.google.com/books?id=vi8wAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=Antique%20No.%203&source=bl&ots=Rxo9K1zdGW&sig=1Itp6RZ1sXDuA2iwyYhlJ-Cfhnw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtirOdp5DSAhVEzoMKHQspB1gQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false)*:

[image]

[image]

Digital versions samples of [Antique 3](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/woodentypefonts/antique3/) designed in 2005 with some deviations. Roundness leading into serifs, extra embelishment on the numbers `2` and `7` (just to name a few). However, the most distinct character (the capital `Q`) along with the "flipped" foot of the capital `R` match closely with the original specimen and the *Kiln* varieties by extension:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow it's amazing, thanks a lot @zeethreepio!! 

I've been digging in your direction, turns out Hoefler & Co are referencing it as an inspiration for their Sentinel font (https://www.typography.com/fonts/sentinel/history/).

I also reckon that the sans serif version is basically just a stripped down version of this font !

Comment: Good call on the Sentinel inspiration, I can definitely see the likeness. I agree on the Sans Serif version of Kiln. They basically just cut off the slab serifs and the decoration on the foot of the 'R' (they must really like that 'Q' though). It looks like Yellow Design Studio used this as inspiration for another font available on their site as well. Check out [Wausau](http://www.yellowdesignstudio.com/fonts/wausau).

Comment: I got in touch with them, turns out Wausau is the base for Kiln.